# When working with a post, almost all wp_postmeta are deleted

Tags: php, posts, custom-field, updates, post-meta

Almost all wp_postmeta removed after updating, deleting POSTS or editing ACF fields, messages what could be wrong?

If you export SQL tables before and after, you will get this:

[image]

**u.p.d**

A request before and after the update:

```
var_dump('SELECT post_id,meta_value,meta_key FROM '.$wpdb->postmeta.' WHERE post_id = 3045');
```

*Result 'good' Before:*

[image]

---

*Result 'bad' after:*

[image]

P.S Sorry for my english I'm using GOOGLE TRANSLATE :)

Comment: Some of those DB entries are temporary. Are you sure anything of value are being deleted from DB?

Comment: @Fayaz Deletes all necessary data.  As well as user ACF fields disappear.   When deleting records from the recycle bin, when changing and updating ACF fields

Comment: No known WP feature or bug does that. So it's either a plugin/theme or some kind of malware that's doing it. Check your WP files with security software. Temporarily, you may try disabling DB delete access to the DB user you use with WP.

Comment: @Fayaz If you disable all plug-ins and delete entries from the Recycle Bin, the required data wil  also be lost.


 Why is this?

 I  add a dynamic key_meta_ (count), can this be related?

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood you correctly. This is all hypothetical talk. You need to employ some one with access to your site. This issue is unlikely to be solved by this sort of discussion.

Just a note: Disabling plugins should not delete related plugin data, however, deleting plugins do delete plugin data if you delete them from Admin panel, this is done by design. However, it depends on plugin developers how they implement it.